# Bootstrap Modal does not show up in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

When i click on Show Modal, the myModal modal does not show up.
Instead the URL on browser window itself changes to /myapp/#myModal (unexpected)
What am i doing wrong here?

```
<div>
<label>I am main page.....</label>
....
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="addressModal" >Show Modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div>Hello I am Modal...</div>
    <div>Whatever....</div>
</div>
...
</div>
```

I have following included in my app: twitter bootstrap 2.3.1, and ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js

Comment: You need to follow the angular-ui api for modals.  It looks like you are trying to use the bootstrap api for it. Look at the documentation: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: Make sure the data-target is correct (ie: `data-target=#myModal`), and remove the `fade` class from the modal markup

Comment: JoseM> As far as i understand...The angula-ui modals will result in a new scope/controller for modal ... i want to open part of my page as a modal within the existing scope.